# Security - Is there a tool for Gmail that integrate in Desktop and does not ask my password (Oauth?)

Tags: security, password, gmail

I am a new user of Linux and I love it so far.

I am also a great fan of Google products and I was searching for a Gmail app that could tell me when I have unread emails.

Unfortunately, all these apps are asking my password and I don't know if that's a good idea.

I was thinking I could login on a webpage (oauth or similar?) so I am sure the app does not know my password.

Do you know a workaround or an official app I can trust to get notified when Gmail mail arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new ubuntu webapps might be answer to your question.

It isn't ready yet. However you can test it via ppa in 12.04.

Full details : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/ubuntu-unveil-new-web-apps-feature-for-12-10

PPA for preview:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

However, this requires that the page is kept open in browser.

Also you can use Google chrome desktop notification feature. (This also require the mail to be kept open in browser page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether GMail supports the newly-developed Ubuntu Web Apps, but you could give it a try.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/install-new-ubuntu-webapps-technology.html